# Determining risks of traffic interception to Cloud SQL from VMs

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-networking

Lets say I have a VM instance and I then make a connection to the Cloud SQL instances IP using a MySQL client.  According to the comparison table in [Connection Options for External Applications](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/external-connection-methods), connecting with no SSL is apparently not secure (and non-encrypted).

But to what extent is it insecure? If there is a man-in-the-middle attack, query and query results could be seen.  I would like to determine how big of a risk that is.

Specifically I would like to know the risks of connecting from:

- A VM in the exact same zone to a Cloud SQL instance
- A VM in the same region, but a difference zone to a Cloud SQL instance
- A VM in another region to a Cloud SQL instance, but still from GCP

I assume that for any of these kinds of attacks to be carried out, the actual google infrastructure would have to have been compromised as it wouldn't be possible for a VM to listen to traffic outside a network that it's attached to.

Comment: Hey there! This question would fit better in Server Fault! Could you move it to that website? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try and get it moved to Server Vault.

Answer (score 1):

The actual infrastructure wouldn't have to be compromised actually, all that it'd take is for an instance in the same network to be compromised for the details of your connection to Cloud SQL to potentially be compromised. Seeing as maintaining the instances up-to-date is a [responsibility of the users](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6262505?hl=en), that means that the security of an insecure connection to Cloud SQL also depends on the security of your instances.

Why exactly are you doing insecure connections? I ask because it's incredibly easy to setup a safe connection from an instance to Cloud SQL by using Cloud SQL Proxy! Not to toot my own horn here, but take a look at 
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48926540/994308) I gave a while ago about why you should be using the Proxy.

Regardless, and keeping in mind that Cloud SQL is nothing more than a managed instance exclusively accessible via its public IP, the traffic should stay within GCP in all three of those scenarios, meaning the only thing that is likely to be compromised are the instances in the same sub-network as that of the instance that's connecting to Cloud SQL.

Comment: Less work or setup is basically the reason.  It may be better to go the SQL Proxy direction anyway.  But still I'm confused why you said that compromised instances on the same sub-network get details of Cloud SQL connections.  Are you 100% sure other instances can eavesdrop in this way?  This would basically mean gcp networks give the level of security of a network hub, not even a switch.

Comment: You're raising a valid question, I just assumed that was the case from past experiences. I'll try investigating this.

Comment: You were right, I just gave it a go and it's not the case. I'm going to edit the response. Dumb mistake, duh...

Comment: Well, I edited the language of the first paragraph without removing it outright. Yes, instances have their traffic isolated from one another, mitigating stuff like ARP spoofing and just straight traffic captures, but that doesn't stop a compromised instance from being used to get into other instances and whatnot. That's my bottom line with that first paragraph. I guess connection encryption is meaningless is your MySQL client instance gets hacked anyway... :)

Comment: Nonetheless, give the SQL Proxy a try! It's super easy to setup, it's literally just a binary, you give it a few arguments, and boom, you have a secure line with a Cloud SQL instance!